# ssrs creating drop down list for search options

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report with Wild Card search option as below which works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%'+ @param1 +'%' OR column2 LIKE '%'+ @param2 +'%'
```

But how to have a drop down for column names and then a single text box to search. I used this and set default value of parameter's each Available Value as column names, but report returns no results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE @columns LIKE '%'+ @param +'%'
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to have all possibilities and get ALL (with OR <>) if that column isn't the one selected to filter on.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column1 LIKE '%'+ @param1 +'%' OR @COLUMNS <> 'COLUMN1')
OR (column2 LIKE '%'+ @param1 +'%' OR @COLUMNS <> 'COLUMN2')
...
```

You could instead add a calculated field (named PARAMETER_COLUMN) on the dataset and filter it in SSRS:

```
=IIF(Parameters!COLUMNS.Value = "COLUMN1", Fields!column1.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!COLUMNS.Value = "COLUMN2", Fields!column2.Value, 
 IIF(Parameters!COLUMNS.Value = "COLUMN3", Fields!column3.Value, Fields!column4.Value)))
```

And then filter on the calculated field:

```
Expression: Fields!PARAMETER_COLUMN.Value
Value: Parameters!param1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to use dynamic query to generate the report:

1. create a dataset for your report's column parameter, something like

   select name from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('your table')
2. change your report query to a dynamic query, you can do it through tsql or simply by using reporting service expression.

But when using dynamic query, you need to consider data type casting and obviously, sql injection issue, as the value will be inputted by end users.